# How to disable drag event from jdialog title bar in mac osx?

Tags: java, macos, swing

I want to disable drag from title bar in Mac osx. I don't know how to do it. I tried different things but not working. I don't want to undecorate jdialog. I need title bar but in some conditions I want to disable drag using title bar.

```
JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
dialog.setBounds(50, 50, 500, 500);
dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Is it possible with swing ?

Comment: what do you mean disabling drag from title bar ? can you please rephrase?

Comment: If I clicks on jdialog title bar and drag jdialog then it is moving. I want to disable that movement.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the below line it removes the window decorations like close maximise and minimise(titlebar). This itself disables the dragging only with mouse events.

`dialog.setUndecorated(true);`

Your Question is copy of [this](http://qnundrum.com/answer.php?q=979633)

Comment: It will completely hide title bar. I want title bar but in some conditions I don't want drag using title bar.

Comment: Some conditions !!! what do you mean by it ? in some scenario it should work and in some it should not !! will you tell me what you want to do exactly ?

Comment: Have you used JFrame as a container ?

Comment: Ya in some it should drag and in some it should not drag. jframe also same property.

Comment: Means titlebar should be there but can't be drag ?

Comment: This one help you http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Dialog.ModalityType.html#APPLICATION_MODAL

Comment: This is near about to your question, see this link and study method http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JDialog.html#JDialog%28java.awt.Frame,%20boolean%29

Comment: component listner will not work because componentMoved will be called when i will stop drag. If window disables then in Mac Osx we are allowed to move using title bar. Modality also I can,t use because it can be used in parent child hierarchy but there is not child for that jdialog. On more thing is after setting modal everything will block which I dont want.

Comment: Ok then you can use above solution that is of `public JDialog(Frame owner,boolean modal)` that uses `DEFAULT_MODALITY_TYPE`